# Не работает WinExec в DLL библиотеке

Tags: delphi, dll

```
WinExec(PANsiChar('TASKKILL /F /IM gta-vc.exe'), SW_HIDE);
```

Не работает в DLL библиотеке (неизвестная деректива).

> [DCC Error] Unit2.pas(27): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'WinExec'

Подключение `Windows` в блок `uses` не помогает.

Comment: Если откроете модуль Windows.pas - там должна быть строчка `function WinExec; external kernel32 name 'WinExec';` Какая у Вас версия Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить `ShellExecute`. Да и желательно увидеть бы, что у вас там в `uses` подключено!